# Angular trigger child function once parent finishes with observables in forEach

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In parent component I am pushing the response of observables to an array which I am passing to child component.

**parent.component.ts**

```
let categoriesArr = [];

for (let category of listing.categories) {
      this._projectService.getCategories().subscribe((data) => {
             this.categoriesArr.push(data);
       });
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<child-comp #childComp [categories]="categoriesArr"></child-comp>
```

In the child component I want to call a specific function once the for loop of observables is finished in parent function.

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() public categories;

public limitCategories() {
**//I want to call this function from parent once the for loop with observables is finished**
...
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<div class="Category" *ngFor="let item of categories">
...
</div>
```

I've tried making the categoriesArr as an Observable, and then subscribe to it in the child component, but then I would call **`limitCategories()`** every time there's a change. I want to call it only once after the last call to the service is made.

Comment: Your for loop will not make the Observables synchronous, use `concatMap()` if you want to call one Observable after the other, have a property in parent with `@viewChild('childComp')` decorator, call child's method using this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `@ViewChild` decorator to get child reference as `ChildComponent`:

**parent.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('childComp', {read: ChildComponent})
childComp: ChildComponent;
```

Then in the loop, you could call `limitCategories()` method:

```
for (let category of listing.categories) {
  this._projectService.getCategories().subscribe((data) => {
         this.categoriesArr.push(data);

         this.childComp.limitCategories();

   });
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you would like to wait the loop of async operations and trigger `limitCategories()` after the last async operation, you could use `async/await` to wait for operations to finish.

**parent.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.getCategories();
}


getCategories = async () => {
    for (let category of listing.categories) {
       await this._projectService.getCategories().toPromise().then((data) => 
       {
           this.categoriesArr.push(data);
       });
    }

    this.childComp.limitCategories();

}
```

Comment: I use @ViewChild, just didn't put it here as it's irrelevant for the problem I'm facing.  Your solution will trigger limitCategories multiple times, and is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: For some reason childComp is undefined. If I place it inside the promise response it's working, but then again making multiple calls

Comment: Maybe you can make the call in `ngAfterViewInıt()`?

Comment: Same problem, I don't know why it doesn't get the reference for the child component, and if I put it anywhere else, it does the job

Comment: I was using Observable and making a subscribtion to it. I've changed to a promise like you initially did, and it works now. I didn't know await only waits for promises.

Comment: My bad. I should've mentioned that change. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `forkJoin` operator :

```
const calls$ = listing
  .categories
  .map(category => this._projectService.getCategories(category))

forkJoin(calls$).subscribe(data => {
  this.categoriesArr = [...data];
  this.childComp.limitCategories();
})
```

Once all of your HTTP calls have been made, `forkJoin` will call the child method.

I'm not saying your implementation is the best solution, but this should do the trick for you.